# QGIS Data Frame scale

Tags: qgis, scale

I am trying to setup the Data Frame in QGIS to a minimum scale of 1:0 like ArcMap does. Zooming in goes down to 25.000:1

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Scale of a map is the ratio of a distance on the map to the corresponding distance on the ground. Neither can't be 0. ArcGIS can't go to 1:0 scale and it doesn't.

Comment: I understand that. 1:1 should be minimum then.

Comment: Not sure if you can set a limit so that the scale cannot go beyond certain values. An alternative could be to set the **Scale dependent visibility** (_Layer Properties > General_) so that the layer is only visible between a minimum and maximum scale.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. I tried different things and the scale still goes beyond 1:1 when zoomed in. I guess I can't change that!

Comment: @Fflavioo - You're probably right that it can't be changed. You _might_ be able to set a fixed scale using Python but that's beyond me :)